# how to display social media button like facebook and twitter on page header or footer

Tags: asp.net, html, css

i want to display facebook and twitter button on my asp.net website
here is the following css code
now i have two images one facebook and other twitter

```
/* Header CSS */
#header{
    background:#10394d;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #195b7c, #10394d);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #195b7c, #10394d);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #195b7c, #10394d);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #195b7c, #10394d);
    background-image:linear-gradient(top, #195b7c, #10394d);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient

(startColorStr='#ff195b7c', endColorStr='#ff10394d', GradientType=0);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient

(startColorStr='#ff195b7c', endColorStr='#ff10394d', GradientType=0)";
    border-bottom: 5px solid #e9970a;
}
.logo{
    float:left;
    margin:25px 30px;
}

.facebook{
    background-image: url(~/img/question.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
.menu{
    background:#c1c1c1;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #c1c1c1);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #c1c1c1);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #c1c1c1);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #c1c1c1);
    background-image:linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #c1c1c1);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient

(startColorStr='#ffffffff', endColorStr='#ffc1c1c1', GradientType=0);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient

(startColorStr='#ffffffff', endColorStr='#ffc1c1c1', GradientType=0)";
    min-height:45px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-topright:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip:padding;
    background-clip:padding-box;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.menu li{
    line-height:32px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
    padding:6px 10px;
}
.menu a{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#b2b2b2;
    float:left;
    padding:0 12px;
}
.menu a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu li:hover a{
    color:#888888;
    padding-top:1px;
}
.menu li.active a{
    color:#fff;
    background:#e9970a;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip:padding;
    background-clip:padding-box;
}
.menu .dropdown-menu-1{
    background-color:#237096;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:45px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip:padding;
    background-clip:padding-box;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.menu li:hover .dropdown-menu-1{
    display:block;

}
.menu .dropdown-menu-1 li{
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:18px;
    float:none;
}
.menu .dropdown-menu-1 li:last-child{
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
.menu .dropdown-menu-1 li:hover{
    background:#e9970a;
}
.menu .dropdown-menu-1 a{
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:normal;
    float:none;
    padding:0;
}
.menu li.active .dropdown-menu-1 a{
    background:none;
}
.menu .dropdown-menu-1 a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.menu li:hover .dropdown-menu-1 a{
    color:#fff;
}
```

and i use that css class in my master page just like this

```
<div class="header">

        <div class="title">
            <h1>
                My ASP.NET Application
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </div>
        <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the problem, where is your html?

Comment: Do we have to decide header or footer?

Comment: Usually people put it in header or on the side where the social media buttons are visible.  So it is easy to spot if the visitor wants to add you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.loginDisplay {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.icons {
  float: right;
}
.facebook {
  background-image: url('http://www.governancenow.com/images/facebook.png');
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.twitter {
  background-image: url('http://kmwordsmith.com/images/round-sm-icons-twitter.gif');
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>
                My ASP.NET Application
            </h1>

  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="loginDisplay"> <span class="bold"> Welcome! [Log in]</span>

    </div>
    <div class="icons">
      <a href="#" class="facebook"></a>
      <a href="#" class="twitter"></a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good one!  Using your own website's social media to link as an example.